# How to put overflow from top to bottom

Tags: html, css

How to make the overflow that way so the image to cut from top to bottom , not from bottom to top ? How to turn the usual effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

could try by setting the image as background?

```
background:url('image.jpg') bottom center;
```

then have fixed height? Thats the only way I can think

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#id {
background: url('image.jpg') bottom center;
width:50px;
height:50px;
}
```

You'll have to change the height and width accordingly to fit your image.

Hope this helps.